# CMAKE missing: X11_EXECUTABLE)

Tags: x11, cmake

I'm trying to compile a program using CMAKE, but it requires X11 to be installed. I have X11 installed on my system. When I run `apt-file find x11.so` I get the output:

```
aeolus: /usr/lib/aeolus/aeolus_x11.so
banshee: /usr/lib/banshee/Backends/libbnpx11.so
baresip-x11: /usr/lib/baresip/modules/x11.so
fcitx-module-x11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fcitx/fcitx-x11.so
gmerlin-plugins-base: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gmerlin/plugins/i_x11.so
gmerlin-plugins-base: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gmerlin/plugins/ov_x11.so
keepassx: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/keepassx/libkeepassx-autotype-x11.so
kwin-x11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_kwin_x11.so
libdirectfb-extra: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/directfb-1.7-7/systems/libdirectfb_x11.so
libjogl2-jni: /usr/lib/jni/libnativewindow_x11.so
libsuil-0-0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/suil-0/libsuil_x11.so
libva-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-x11.so
libva-x11-2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-x11.so.2
libva-x11-2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-x11.so.2.100.0
libxkbcommon-x11-0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon-x11.so.0
libxkbcommon-x11-0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon-x11.so.0.0.0
libxkbcommon-x11-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon-x11.so
mir-platform-graphics-mesa-x13: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mir/server-platform/server-mesa-x11.so.13
mit-scheme: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mit-scheme/lib/prx11.so
plymouth-x11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plymouth/renderers/x11.so
scim: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/scim-1.0/1.4.0/FrontEnd/x11.so
transcode: /usr/lib/transcode/import_x11.so
```

But then running my CMAKE commands I get the error:

```
Starting build with cmake...
-- Could NOT find x11 (missing: X11_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Could NOT find x11 (missing: X11_EXECUTABLE) 
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/Geant4InterfaceOptions.cmake:229 (message):
  could not find X11 Xmu library and/or headers
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/G4CMakeMain.cmake:65 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:55 (include)
```

I've gone through all the threads on this issue and done all recommendations, such as `apt-get install libx11-dev libx11-devel` and more. What else can I do to fix this?

Comment: `x11.so` is a library, not executable. You have to pass something like `/usr/bin/X`.

Comment: »» could not find X11 **Xmu** library and/or headers «« : Install `libXmu`! ..... Fedora, CentOS : `# yum install libXmu-devel` ..... Debian, Ubuntu : `$ sudo apt install libxmu-dev`

Comment: Thank you! Installing the Xmu library fixed the issue.